# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, imagick, bitnami

**I'm using an AWS EC2 Bitnami AMI**: bitnami-lampstack-5.4.11-1-linux-ubuntu-12.04.1-x86_64-ebs (ami-aadf4cc3)

**I have a php file:**

```
<?php 
    $im = new imagick();
    $im->readImageBlob(file_get_contents("http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.jpg"));
?>
```

**That gives me the following error:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/index.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/index.php(3): Imagick->readimageblob('??????JFIF?????...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/index.php on line 3
```

**I installed imagick using the following steps:**

```
1) wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
    2) tar -zxvf imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
    3) cd imagick-3.1.0RC2
    4) phpize
    5) ./configure
    6) make
    7) make install
```

**So far, I've tried:**

```
1) file_get_contents is returning the image file and it is a confirmed jpeg
2) using convert directly from the command line --> it works
3) imagick-3.0.1 on this AMI and it won't install because of compiler errors
4) imagick-3.0.1 on the previous bitnami AMI (bitnami-lampstack-5.3.10-2-linux-ubuntu-12.04-x86_64-ebs (ami-8c4c96e5)) and it gives the same ImagickException error (no decode delegate)
5) Using a PNG file which gives me the same error
```

**Convert -list configure gives me DELEGATES bzlib freetype jpeg jng png tiff zlib**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

update `/opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh` as follows with

`MAGICKCODERMODULE_PATH="/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.6.9/modules-Q16/coders"`

**THEN**

```
`/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`
```

Comment: Choose your own answer as the right one to help others looking for a similar solution.

Comment: It's `MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH`, not `MAGICKCODERMODULE_PATH`.